# ignore directories using modrewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

so I have a blog at blog/

I want to prevent yii (framework) from rewriting the urls in the blog/ directory.

how do I do that using modrewrite?

Here is my .htaccessfile:

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
#RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog`

For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
#RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

In this way, all sequent rules will be applied if the request url doesn't match the word 'blog'.